# How to easily link a document with others

Tags: microsoft-word, google-docs

Let's say that I am writing some text document in word or whatever text editor or online wit google docs, etc. Let's say that at some part of the document I open a new one and extend there the idea. Then later, I go back to the "master" document and add some hyperlink or just put reference (it follows in doc XXXX, page YYYY). I wonder what could be the fastest approach to do this

- google docs adding easily hyperlink? but how can I organize docs effectively?
- some text editor with this functionality?

Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depend on what you want write I would recommend a wiki (mediawiki for example). For me the important factors are:

- online
- easy to use
- if I want I own it (no external server, software whatever. Just install it on your computer. With lamp and co its really easy)
- you can share your documents. just open the port to your server
- versioncontrol, never loose any data
- easy backups

Comment: by the way, which is the easiest wiki system to install on a mac?

Comment: are there similar sysmtes not being wiki? (they seem hard to set up)

Comment: I used http://www.tiddlywiki.com/ for some time, because it didn't needed a database. Later i moved to mediawiki, because I did like to know it better. For Mac http://www.mamp.info/ is the LAMP bundle. I never tried it, but if it works similar to lamp it will install everything you'll need for your wiki installation.